# TypeError: unbound method amount () must be called with loan instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Tags: python-2.7

```
import datetime


class Loan:
    def __init__(self, principal, rate, date):
        self.p=principal
        self.r=rate
        self.d=date

    def amount(self):
        interest=self.r*self.p
        now=datetime.date.today()
        delta=datetime.timedelta(1)
        then=self.d
        while then <= now:
            print then.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            print outstanding 
            outstanding +=interest
            then+=delta


x=Loan
x.p=10000
x.r=0.1/7
x.d=datetime.date.today()-
    datetime.timedelta(5)
x.amount()
```

I expected to get the date and outstanding amount for each interval but I get an error, I checked past solutions and cross checked with my code to make sure the method was called on an instance. The error I get when I run the code is :

TypeError: unbound method amount () must be called with loan instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

Comment: you'll want to instantiate the class `Loan` into an object first (using parentheses `Loan()`) before operating on its methods, try `p=10000
r=0.1/7
d=datetime.date.today() - datetime.timedelta(5)

x=Loan(p,r,d)`

Comment: x=Loan() perfectly worked out. Merci. x=Loan(p,r,d) gives the error 'constructor takes no argument'.  So instantiating each argument at a time solves it.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime


class Loan:
    def __init__(self, principal = 0, rate = 0, date = 0):
        self.p=principal
        self.r=rate
        self.d=date

    def amount(self):
        interest=self.r*self.p
        now=datetime.date.today()
        delta=datetime.timedelta(1)
        then=self.d
        outstanding = 0
        while then <= now:
            print then.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
            print outstanding 
            outstanding +=interest
            then+=delta


x= Loan()
x.p=10000
x.r=0.1/7
x.d=datetime.date.today()-datetime.timedelta(5)
x.amount()
```

give default values to the constructor args.